# Artifact without scala binary version

Tags: sbt

Is it possible to publish an additional artifact without the Scala binary version (_x.xx) being appended?

I am aware of the `crossPaths` setting, however I would like to publish my main artifact with a version string, and an additional one without.

Comment: Since no one else is answering, I offer this possibly feeble suggestion: you could define an additional configuration, override the artifact name in that configuration, and then publish twice, once from the normal configuration and once from the one you added.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Hi **Seth Tisue** can you provide more detail, regarding additional configuration please.